# How to use the appropriate index while querying mongo using mongospark connectors via withPipeline feature?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am trying to load huge amount of data from mongodb. Data size is in millions. So, it makes sense to pull this data using appropriate indexes and also query mongo in parallel. Thats why to do batch reads, I am using mongo spark.
How to use the appropriate index while querying mongo using mongospark connectors via withPipeline feature?

Also, I was exploring "com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection". If possible, can someone throw some light on this?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words for measurements

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean, is mongodb not using an appropriate index? It should use an index based on your query

Comment: Yes, mongo isnt using appropriate index. Its using some random index. Basically, it is not finding the right index thats why I wanted to explicitly specify the index.